# How to bind DataList inside a DataList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, datalist, nested-datalist

! am having a nested `DataList` and I want to bind inner `DataList` on `button` event, but it's not working, anyone have an idea?

```
DataList2.FindControl("DataList3").DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to `Bind` Inner `DataList` :

```
protected void DataList2_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || 
             (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        // get inner datalist
        DataList dl3 = e.Item.FindControl("DataList3") as DataList;

        // bind inner datalist with data source
        dl3.DataSource = dt; // DataTable that contains data
        dl3.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Note:** 
Make sure you have entered this event `OnItemDataBound="DataList2_ItemDataBound"` like this:

`<asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DataList2_ItemDataBound">`

Answer (score 0):

Try to cast it with datalist

```
((DataList)DataList2.FindControl("DataList3")).DataBind();
```